# How to empty input field in combination with a range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, input

I have a range slider with a min and max value, which is binded by ng-model with an input field.
But it's not possible to have a empty input field, by backspace the value of the input field is always the minimum value or the halfway between the specified minimum and maximum.

How to make it possible that the input field is also empty on backspace, so the user can fill self a value?

Example:
If the user want to fill for example 250 as the value, he needs to select the value in the input field with CTRL+A and replace the value with 250. Now it's not possible tohange the 1 (from the minimum) with 2 to fill 250. Other option is by using the arrows on the keyboard.

```
<input type="number"
    ng-model="sliderElement.value"
    ng-change="setRange()">

<input type="range" 
    ng-model="sliderElement.value" 
    min="{{rangeSliderMinValue}}" max="{{rangeSliderMaxValue}}" 
    step="{{rangeSliderStep}}" 
    ng-change="setRange()"/>
```

JS:

```
this.sliderElement.value = 50;
this.rangeSliderMinValue = 1;
this.rangeSliderMaxValue = 400;
this.rangeSliderStep = 1;

setRange() {
const rangeSliderElement = this.element[0].querySelector('.range-slider').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

const val = (rangeSliderElement.value - this.rangeSliderMinValue) / (this.rangeSliderMaxValue - this.rangeSliderMinValue);

rangeSliderElement.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
     + 'color-stop(' + val + ', red), '
     + 'color-stop(' + val + ', green)'
     + ')';
}
```

Comment: Are you using a directive for your slider? It's a little confusing because in your javascript you are selecting on a `range-slider` class, but that class does not exist in the markup you've shown.

Comment: No the range-slider is the div container outside the input tag.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] because I just tried a small test and I was able to clear out the input with no issue. Or maybe I'm not understanding exactly what issue you're experiencing.